# Using STR_TO_Date() in mysql insert

Tags: mysql

i have mysql table as follows

```
 CREATE TABLE `installments` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`order` int(11) NOT NULL,
`payment_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`cost` int(11) NOT NULL,
`is_paid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`is_removed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

when i run insert statment

```
     INSERT INTO installments (`order`,payment_date,cost) VALUES     (1,STR_TO_DATE('5-30-2017','%m-%d-%y'),14
```

gives me 
Data truncation: Truncated incorrect date value: '5-30-2017

any ideas how to fix this

Comment: Can you pad your month before you pass it in? It's looking for a 2 digit month (01-12), and you're passing in a single digit month.

Comment: I take that back, try `%c` instead of `%m`

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
INSERT INTO installments (`order`,payment_date,cost) VALUES     (1,STR_TO_DATE('5-30-2017','%m-%d-%y'),14
```

TO

```
 INSERT INTO installments (`order`,payment_date,cost) VALUES     (1,STR_TO_DATE('5-30-2017','%m-%d-%Y'),14)
```

Comment: Did you try mysql default Y-m-d format instead m-d-y format?

Comment: Please, always store dates as a Y-m-d form in MySQL. If you need to select it in another form, use the correct string function DATE_FORMAT!

Answer (score 0):

The [date format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) you're using expected the month to be formatted with a leading zero (01-12). You want `%c`, which drops the leading zero:

```
INSERT INTO installments (`order`,payment_date,cost) VALUES
 (1,STR_TO_DATE('5-30-2017','%c-%d-%Y'),14);
```

Comment: It should also be %Y instead of %y, since it's 4 digits and not 2. I'm not sure if that would help.

Comment: Actually running a temporary table on my server, `%m-%d-%y` and '%c-%d-%y` gave that warning, while `%c-%d-%Y` worked fine, so it should work.